# How to use USB API with any USB device?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I've created an app that uses the USB API to open a new tab when the USB device is connected.

But now I want to improve it a bit. Before, when I use USB API I must define its `vendorID` and `productID` in the manifest. It means my app only use exactly one USB device.

Now I want any USB to interact with my app. Anybody can give me an idea to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I do believe it's impossible for security reasons. You can specify more than one PID/VID pair, but you cannot ask for arbitrary ones.

The [stated reason](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb#manifest) for this is to prevent apps from [fingerprinting hardware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) by enumerating *all* connected USB devices, which has a good chance to be a unique set.