# how to enumerate connected USB and Wi-Fi devices in chrome app development

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app

sample code attached

manifest.json

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Devices",
  "version": "0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "26",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
 "permissions": [
 "usb",
    {"usbDevices": [
      {
        "vendorId": 1234,
        "productId": 145
      }
    ]}
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {id:"fileWin", bounds: {width: 800, height: 500}}, function(win) {
    win.contentWindow.launchData = launchData;
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Devices</title>

        <style>
            button {
                    display: inline-block;
                    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#F9F9F9 40%, #E3E3E3 70%);
                    background: linear-gradient(#F9F9F9 40%, #E3E3E3 70%);
                    border: 1px solid #999;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    padding: 5px 8px;
                    outline: none;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    -webkit-user-select: none;
                    user-select: none;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
                    font-weight: 700;
                    font-size: 10pt;
                }
            button:not(:disabled):hover {
                    border-color: black;
                }
            button:not(:disabled):active {
                    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#E3E3E3 40%, #F9F9F9 70%);
                    background: linear-gradient(#E3E3E3 40%, #F9F9F9 70%);
                }
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Devices<br><br>
            <nav>
                    <button id="usb_dev" onclick="GetUsbDevices()">USB</button>
                    <button id="wifi_dev" ">Wi-Fi</button>
            </nav>
        </p
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
function GetUsbDevices() 
{
    //alert('Clicked USB Device Button');
   console.log("Device could not be found");

}
```

i am trying to display connected devices to Application window.As i am new in this developing ,not succeeding.

Please help thanks in advance, Sarath s

Comment: Your inclusion of code is a bit useless: it's a skeleton with no functionality related to the question at hand, so basically you show no attempt at solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe both of your tasks are impossible to achieve (without a [Native Host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging), anyway).

1. USB enumeration is specifically disallowed for security purposes, that I outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137321/how-to-use-usb-api-with-any-usb-device):

   > The stated reason for this is to prevent apps from fingerprinting hardware by enumerating all connected USB devices, which has a good chance to be a unique set.
2. It's unclear what you mean by "WiFi devices"; you can enumerate network interfaces with `chrome.system.network` API, but any kind of device discovery on the network would highly depend on what you meant.

   You cannot enumerate WiFi networks, and you will have to implement your own, specific discovery for services (as long as it's possible using `chrome.socket.tcp`/`chrome.socket.udp`).